# Moving data from local MSSQL server to a remote MYSQL DB

Tags: mysql, ssis, odbc

I am using SSIS to move data between a local MSSQL server table to a remote MYSQL table (Data flow, OLEdb source and ODBC Destination). this works fine if im only moving 2 lines of data, but is very slow when using the table I want which has 5000 rows that fits into a csv of about 3mb, this currently takes about 3 minutes using ssis's options, however performing the steps below can be done in 5 seconds max).

I can export the data to a csv file copy it to the remote server then run a script to import straight to the DB, but this requires a lot more steps that I would like as I have multiple tables I wish to perform the steps on.

I have tried row by row and batch processing but both are very slow in comparison.

I know I can use the above steps but I like using the SSIS GUI and would have thought there was a better way of tackling this.

I have googled away multiple times but have not found anything that fits the bill so am calling on external opinions.

I understand SSIS has its limitations but I would hope there is is a better and faster way of achieving what I am trying to do.  If SSIS is so bad I may as well just rewrite everything into a script and be done with it, But I like the look and feel of the Gui and would like to move my data in this nice friendly way of seeing things happen.

any suggestions or opinions would be appreciated.

thank you for your time.

As above have tried ssis options including a 3rd party option cozyroc but that sent some data with errors (delimiting on columns seemed off) now and again, different amount of rows being copied and enough problems to make me not trust the data.

Comment: To identify the cause, try replacing the destination with a flat file destination. If performance is not increased then you have to check the OLE DB Source configuration else it is related to the ODBC destination.

Comment: Can you post a ping time to remote MYSQL database?

Comment: Very strange I cant ping the sever but can connect using a client and see and query all of the db's and tables.  I will defiantly bring that up.

Comment: @Yahfoufi If I export the data to a flat file it does so in a very short amount of time, (1 - 2 Seconds) where as the ODBC connection can take a very long time to transfer the data, I was just assuming it was trying to do it row by row. but something else seems to be at play.